# The maximum value of $PA\cdot PB\cdot PC$

Tags: geometry, optimization, triangles

Let $A,B,C$ be the vertices of a triangle inscribed in a unit circle, and let $P$ be a point in the interior or on the sides of the $\triangle{ABC}$ .Then the maximum value of $PA\cdot PB\cdot PC$ equals to?
$(A)\frac{41}{27}\hspace{1cm}(B)\frac{43}{27}\hspace{1cm}(C)\frac{32}{27}\hspace{1cm}(D)\frac{29}{27}$

---

I think this problem will be solved by Fermat's point of a triangle.$PA\cdot PB\cdot PC$ is maximum when $PA+PB+PC$ will be minimum and it is minimum at Fermat point which i am not able to find.Please help me .Thanks.

Comment: There is no local maximum in the interior, you need to look for $P$ on the sides.

Comment: ya, you had better to check the vertices.

Comment: What does $(PA)(PB)(PC)$ mean ?

Comment: @achillehui,Sir,how can you say that there is no local maximum in the interior.

Comment: @calculus,PA is distance between P and A,PB is distance between P and B,PC is distance between P and C.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia see my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1380954/59379) to a related question.

Comment: @achillehui,how should i find maximum PA.PB.PC then,any hints or some final answer for me to arrive at.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia aside from mapping the problem to complex numbers and convert the problem of finding critical point (along a side of triangle) to solving some cubic equation, I don't have any idea. However, that direction of attack looks very messy to me.

Comment: Are you looking for SUM or MULTIPLICATION? The expression you use is a multiplication but in Q you ask for sum.

Comment: In any case the point is on the longest arc

Comment: The solution is derived by: 1. Observe the behavior along the edges 2, prove that there is no interior point that provides a local maxima (the first comment)

Comment: suppose we have the point p in the interior of the triangle, then, if we keep increasing the size of the triangle, then the product (pa * pb * pc) will get on increasing. then how can we have a maxima?

Comment: Is the problem to maximize the product among all triangles inscribed in a unit circle? Or are we assuming, e.g., that the triangle is equilateral?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space of quadruples $(A,B,C,P)$ which satisfy constrains is a subset of $(\mathbb R^2)^4$, which I am *pretty sure* is compact (if we allow degenerate triangles). Since a map which takes a quadruple to $PA\cdot PB\cdot PC$ is continuous, this means that the maximum is achieved somewhere.

Let $(A,B,C,P)$ be a quadruple which achieves this maximum. First, I claim $P$ is not the center of the circle. This is because $P$ being center necessarily gives the product of lengths to be $1$, but we can do better than that.

Next, I claim $P$ lies on one of the sides. This is trivial if $ABC$ is degenerate. So suppose it isn't and $P$ is strictly inside. Take the unique secant of the circle containing $P$. It divides circle into two arcs. Then at least two of the points $A,B,C$ *don't* lie in the midpoint of the longer arc (call it $M$ for now). Because $P$ is strictly contained in the triangle, if we move one of them a little towards $M$, we will increase its distance from $P$ and hence the product $PA\cdot PB\cdot PC$ (this is very elementary), and we will keep $P$ inside the triangle (this is a bit of handwaving, but I am certain this is true), which is a contradiction with configuration reaching maximum.

So $P$ lies on some side. WLOG, say that $P$ lies on side $AB$. Since $C$ must be at the largest possible distance from $P$, it must lie on the intersection of ray $PO$ with the circle ($O$ is the center). Let $C'$ be intersection of the ray $OP$ with the circle. By power of the point, $PA\cdot PB=PC\cdot PC'$, hence $PA\cdot PB\cdot PC=PC^2\cdot PC'=PC^2(CC'-PC)=PC^2(2-PC)$, as $CC'$ is a diameter. Now we maximize this using calculus or AM-GM inequality, whichever you wish, and we get that the maximum is reached for $PC=\frac{4}{3}$, $PA\cdot PB\cdot PC=\frac{32}{27}$.

It's easy to see from this that the bound is achievable, even by a non-degenerate triangle.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This is a partial answer, since the argumentation is not completely rigorous.

> The following reasoning indicates the solution is $\frac{32}{27}$.
>
> **Approach:** We describe the situation using a coordinate system. We consider the unit circle with center $(0,0)$ and radius $1$.
>
> - Without any loss of generality we may assume that the position of $C$ is $(1,0)$ and the $y$-coordinate of $P$ is $0$ (by proper rotation of the $x,y$-axes).
> - We take the arguments of @achillehui stated in the comment section and assume that $P$ is located on the side $AB$ of the triangle.
> - Assumption (with less rigor): The point $P$ is located in the *middle* of the side $AB$.
>     Reasoning: Often extremal problems with ellipses lead to a circle, or extremal problems with rectangles lead to squares.Since we want to find a maximum, we inherently look rather for a symmetrical solution.
>
> Let $\overline{PX}$ denote the distance from $P$ to $X$. Since the product $\overline{PA}\cdot\overline{PB}\cdot\overline{PC}$ should be a maximum, we may assume that the side $AB$ of the triangle is left to the origin, which implies that the $x$-coordinate of $P$ is less than zero.

We are ready for the calculation.

> **Calculation:**
>
> Let $\varphi$ denote the angle $\angle(A0C)$. The distance $\overline{PC}=\overline{P0}+\overline{0C}=\cos(\varphi)+1$ and the distance $\overline{PA}=\overline{PB}=\sin(\varphi)$. We have to determine $\varphi$, so that
>   \begin{align*}
> f(\varphi)&=\overline{PA}\cdot\overline{PB}\cdot\overline{PC}\\
> &=\sin^2(\varphi)(\cos(\varphi)+1)\\
> &=1+\cos(\varphi)-\cos^2(\varphi)-\cos^3(\varphi)\quad\rightarrow \quad\max
> \end{align*}
>
> Setting
>   \begin{align*}
> f^\prime(\varphi)=\sin(\varphi)(3\cos^2(\varphi)+2\cos(\varphi)-1)=0
> \end{align*}
>   we obtain the solutions
>   \begin{align*}
> \varphi=\begin{cases}
> n\pi\qquad& n\in \mathbb{Z}\\
> \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+2\pi n\qquad& n\in \mathbb{Z}\\
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> The relevant solution is $\varphi=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ and we finally obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
>  f(\varphi)=f\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)=1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{27}=\frac{32}{27}
>  \end{align*}